# Ubuntu Touch — Bluetooth and speakers

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bluetooth-speaker

I have set my new Ubuntu tablet and my new bluetooth speakers. They work great and connect as I turn them both on.

Is there a way I can have the sound coming from both the tablet speakers and the bluetooth speakers at the same time. This way I could have the tablet in one room and the bluetooth speakers in the other and listen to the same music. As currently when the external speakers are connected the tablet speakers go off.

Comment: I bet right now (if you can do this), the audio would be out of sync; the tablet would play audio before the (delayed) bluetooth speakers.

Comment: That sounds like it may new the case but I am sure some developer could overcome this. My wife and I were in the kitchen with the tablet and my son and the speakers were next door. So good if they were both playing. Come on ubuntu lets get this one working ;-)

Comment: I have logged this under the following - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluetooth-touch/+bug/1576963

Comment: I have just received an email saying that the defect that I raised for this has been moved to confirmed as it is affecting multiple users. So lets watch this space as we may get this soon.